# Searching for statistic formula

Tags: excel-formula, statistics

I am trying to find a formula that will represent the best prize from my prizes list.

I have two different variables for each prize:
1. How many people want that prize
2. The amount of money that each of the people who wanted the prize was want to invest in the prize.

For example: 
1. 6 people invests 4 coins each for the prize.
2. 4 people invests 6 coins each for the prize.

In my opinion the amount of peoples have more wight than the money invested.

Is there any formula for this calculation.

Thank

Comment: Put People in column A and Coins in column B, and the formula in C2 is `=A2*B2`.  But, for what it's worth, the weight will be equal - it's just multiplication.  10 people with 2 coins will give you the same result as 2 people with 10 coins.

Comment: This is not what I have meant. There is a big difference between 10 people with 2 coins and 2 people with 10 coins. I need to find the formula that will distinguish the two cases.  Taking in conclusion that the amount of people have more wight than the amount of coins.

Comment: It's unclear what you want your formula to accomplish.  What number should 10 people and 2 coins output?  What number should 2 people and 10 coins output?

Answer (score 0):

how about 
=A2^2*B2
it will emphasize "crowded" options
so 10 persons, 4 coins will be equal to 2 persons, 100 coins or 4 persons 25 coins or 5 persons 16 coins etc.